# How to fetch Azure KeyVault secrets values dynamically in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm using [wapacro](https://github.com/wapacro/az-keyvault-php) library to fetch KeyVault secrets into my laravel app. There's a function to retrieve secrets (not values) `getSecrets()` maximum of 25 secrets. And to retrieve a specific secret there's `getSecret()` function. But I would like to dynamically fetch secrets from keyvault and their values while application(laravel app) loads instead of calling `getSecret()` with one secret name. Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just had to check if the `nextLink` in response from `getSecrets()` is `null` or not. If it is I have to call the function `getSecrets($nextLink)` recursively.